# Using Git to separate code changes when working on more than one issue

Tags: git, tortoisegit, changelist

For context: I am working as a sole developer on a single project.  I recently migrated my SVN repo to Git and the first thing I miss when working with TortoiseGit vs. TortoiseSVN, is changelists, which, in TortoiseSVN, let you group locally-changed files and name those groups, yet still see a list of *all* changes that are uncommitted.  I typically do this when I find myself working on more than one ticket (bug or feature) at the same time before I am ready to commit anything.

Realizing the the Git way of doing things is definitely different from the SVN way, perhaps I should be committing changes locally or even creating a separate branch for each ticket and switching between them?  I am just a little apprehensive since SVN often didn't branch/switch/merge well whenever I did anything out of the ordinary, like renaming (or was it moving) a file.  Also, it's nice to see all of my changed files in a single, grouped list, which changelists give me but I don't see any way to do that in Git.

If, in the case described above, the generally-accepted answer is to use a branch for each ticket, I would like some guidance on the steps for the following two scenarios, please:

1. How to separate my current set of changes, which comprise 18 files in total.  Should I make two branches from the entire current state, Branch for Ticket #1 and Branch for Ticket #2, and then somehow remove #2's changes from branch #1 and visa-versa?
2. For new situations where I already have some code changes for just one ticket and I must start work on a different ticket, what steps should I take so that I can still easily go back and forth between the two and ideally see all changes combined?  Would it go like this?  Create a branch for the current ticket's changes; create a new branch off of master for the second ticket's changes and switch between them as I switch work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In git both creating and merging branches is fast and easy. Branching one of the great strengths of git.

So, best practice is definetely creating a branch for each task you embark on. Even small tasks! That will make it easier to work in a structured way, and the version tree will be easy to understand afterwards.

1. I would do it like this:

   1. Assume that you are on the branch `master`
   2. create a branch for Ticket#1, `git checkout -b ticket1`
   3. Stage the changes that belong to that ticket `git add file1`
   4. `git commit`
   5. Switch back to master `git checkout master` (the file modifications regarding Ticket#2 are preserved)
   6. create a branch for Ticket#2, `git checkout -b ticket2`
   7. Stage the changes that belong to that ticket `git add file2`
   8. `git commit`
   9. Now you can freely switch between the tickets using `git checkout ticket1`
2. Yes. In git it is safe, easy and fast to switch branches. So it totally makes sense to switch between branches for different tasks.

Comment: Your parenthetical remark in step 5 is misleading. I do not understand what it means.

Comment: @j6t In the OP scenario, both files regarding Ticket#1 and Ticket#2 have been modified. Steps 1-4 commits the files regarding Ticket#1, while the files regarding Ticket#2 are still modified, but not committed. In Step 5, you switch branch, but *that will not, as you might fear, reset the modifications that are not yet committed* (which is what I meant in the parenthetical remark). Git will leave those modifications in place, which fits our scenario well, since we proceed to commit those modifications.

Comment: I see. So, there is an implicit step 0. Assume you have fixed both tickets, and the fixes are completely separated in different files.

Comment: @j61 No. You don't have to be finished, but the scenario, as I understood it, was that both tickets had been started, and the OP was considering splitting them into different branches, which I agree is a good idea. After that is done, work can progress independently on each branch. Also, the modifications do not have to be separated in whole files. Git is one of the few version control systems that support partial staging, so that you can commit just some changes of a file. But that is an advanced topic, so I did not cover how to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry to pick nits here. I agree with all you said except that your step 5 will not work if only part of the changes *in one file* were staged in step 3 (e.g., using `git add -p`). Then step 5 must become `git checkout -m master`.

Comment: @j61 ok, fair point about `-m`. But I think I'm going to leave it out of the answer since it is a fairly advanced scenario.

Comment: I appreciate both the clarity of Klas' answer and the additional nuance mentioned by j6t.  Thank you both!  So many parts to Git.  One thing I didn't pick up until I read up on it just now was the "index" or staging area.  Unlike SVN, modifying a versioned file requires `git add`--something that TortoiseGit shielded me from, for better or worse.  Am I correct that if I needed to split a file's changes between branches, I would: 1) make just one set of changes, 2) stage (`svn add`) the file in that state, 3) commit to the desired branch and finally: switch, make more changes, stage, commit?

Comment: @CraigSilver I've always thought that TortoiseGit does hide a bit too much of the underlying functionality. I recommend using Git Extensions instead. About your scenario, yes that is the simplest way to go. But as our discussion has shown, it is possible to start with having differences from both tickets and still disambiguate them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out Git Extensions.